# Reverting CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled in VSCode

Tags: terminal, mojave, font, defaults

I turned on font smoothing in VSCode using the following commands:

```
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled 0
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode.helper CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled 0
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.EH CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled 0
defaults write com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.NP CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled 0
```

This was taken from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/9leavs/fix_mojave_font_rendering_issues_on_a_perapp_basis/).

But how do I revert it back? I tried doing `defaults com.microsoft.VSCode delete -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `defaults write x y z` run `defaults delete x y`,
where *x* is the domain, *y* is the key and *z* is the value.

For example, to delete the first key that was set, run

```
defaults delete com.microsoft.VSCode CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled
```

- Omit the value (e.g. 0) when deleting a key since the key is deleted regardless of value.
- `-g` is a reference to the global domain; if you didn't write the key to the global domain then don't include `-g` when deleting.
- The `delete` or `write` verb needs to go before other options like the domain, not after.